# Disabling background layouts when clicking a button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow

I have two List-views and a button in my XML.On clicking the button a popup box will appear.So i want to disable the underlying layouts when button is clicked.How can i do that ?

**Here is my xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#25232c"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code for popup box

```
// Get the x and y position after the button is draw on screen

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

       int[] location = new int[2];
       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);

       // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
       // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
       button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

       //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
       p = new Point();
       p.x = location[0];
       p.y = location[1];
    }

    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p)
    {
       int popupWidth = 550;
       int popupHeight = 350;

       // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.datepicker_popup, viewGroup);

       // Creating the PopupWindow
       final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
       popup.setContentView(layout);
       popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
       popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
       popup.setFocusable(true);

       // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
       int OFFSET_X = 7;
       int OFFSET_Y = 65;

       // Clear the default translucent background
       popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

       // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);



       // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
       Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
       close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
       {
           /* disable(content_view);*/
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {
            popup.dismiss();
         }
       });
```

Here is my custom layout for popup window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/popup"
            android:layout_width="308dp"
            android:layout_height="224dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/now"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Now" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Done" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Want to disable ListView  on button click??

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes.like in this image http://i.imgur.com/V7ehn3i.png

Comment: Means want to open dialog on click on Button?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes.exactly

Comment: @PiyushGupta Please see this.http://i.imgur.com/sOZyv9d.png...This is my popup box

Comment: R u using custom layout for dialog?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes.Please see it in updated code

Comment: You means your button not aligned properly?

Comment: @PiyushGupta No.Please ignore alignment.I just want to make the background of the popup window have this dark effect and disabled.

Comment: for that you can set background image like that for your custom layout.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Currently am using this image for popup window as background of custom layout.

Comment: Yes its right. So still you did't get output what u want?

Comment: no.its just an image for window http://i.imgur.com/KbLjD2r.png...It appears like the one in the screenshot.It is not full screen

Comment: Move this  android:background="@drawable/popup_bg" to your parent Linear Layout.

Comment: i did that.but the background image is not full screen.It lies behind the popup window.I need it to be full screen

Comment: Here you have defined  int popupWidth = 550;
       int popupHeight = 350; so it will be displayed only that part.

Comment: ohhh.I missed that part.Now its fine :) Thank u so much for the help PiyushGupta.Have a good day :)

Comment: You'r most wel come...

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have another doubt.Could u please help me ?

Comment: Yes..if i know then i will.

Comment: I tried changing the coordinates for position where the popup is shown.But it appears on the top of the screen.How to change it ?

Comment: you need to change here according to your requirement.and set Gravity TOp

Comment: I need to place the popup just below the button for popup.

Comment: for that you can use Popup Menu just check my answer.

Comment: @PiyushGupta am not clear about what u said :(

Comment: My means to say that you can use PopUp menu class which can be display as drop down

Answer (score 1):

you can try
 `listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`  or `listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

when button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

inside `onClick` of button

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =  = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
linearLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kick-off example:

```
final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: This makes the underlying layout invisible na.But what i need is something like in the image.Please see the link.Its just an example of what i need.Not the exact one http://i.imgur.com/V7ehn3i.png

Comment: You are talking about this effect when background became "dark"? It will be done automaticaly when you are showing dialog.